# C# comparing two files regex problem

Tags: c#

what I'm trying to do is open a huge list of files (about 40k records, and match them on a line in a file that contains 2 millions records.  And if my line from file A matches a line in file B write out that line.

File A contains a bunch of files without extensions and file B contains full file paths including extensions.

i'm using this but i cant get it to go...

string alphaFilePath = (@"C:\Documents and Settings\g\Desktop\Arrp\Find\natst_ready.txt");

```
            List<string> alphaFileContent = new List<string>();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(alphaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    alphaFileContent.Add(rdr.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            string betaFilePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\g\Desktop\Arryup\Find\eble.txt";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine();
string matchup = Regex.Match(alphaFileContent, @"(\\)(\\)(\\)(\\)(\\)(\\)(\\)(\\)(.*)(\.)").Groups[9].Value;
                    if (alphaFileContent.Equals(matchup))
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\array_tech.txt", betaFileLine);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This doesnt work because the alphafilecontent is a single line only and i'm having a hard time figuring out how to get my regex to work on the file that contains all the file paths (Betafilepath)

here is a sample of the beta file path.

C:\arres_i\Grn\Ora\SEC\DBZ_EX1\Nes\001\DZO-EX00001.txt

Here is the line i'm trying to compare from my alpha
DZO-EX00001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension instead of a regular expression.

```
    static void Compare(string alpha, string beta)
    {
        HashSet<string> alphaContent = new HashSet<string>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(alpha);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            alphaContent.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        reader.Close();

        reader = new StreamReader(beta);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string fullpath = reader.ReadLine();
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullpath);
            if (alphaContent.Contains(filename))
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\array_tech.txt", fullpath);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you read in all the lines in beta, and have the whole thing stored in a string, `beta`.

Next, you read a line from alpha and have `DZO-EX00001` stored in a string, `alpha`.

```
var pattern = @"^.*" + alpha + ".*$";
var match = Regex.Match(beta, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

if(match.Success)
{
   string filepath = match.Value;
   // do stuff
}
```

You need to load all of the lines from beta first. Then you can check each line from alpha against it.

You must specify `RegexOptions.Multiline` to check against all the lines in `beta` (so that the `^` and `$` will match at each line instead of at the beginning and end of the whole string.

The pattern can be expanded if you need to be more specific; as is, it just gets the first line that contains the filename.